# Is there a better visual than the infamous generic stock photo employee for a human connection?

Tags: symbolism, visualization

We have a strict corporate policy against publishing any photos. In fact one magazine requested a head shot for the cover of their issue and we had to decline that part of our contract.

What are alternatives to employee photos?

Many businesses use the all too famous "generic stock photo" such as:

[image]

Or the even more overused, "girl with hands-free telephone" like this:

[image]

What visual can be used to substitute these relatively poor images? Something that evokes actual emotion and a human connection.

Comment: How about a picture of shaking hands?  Not the whole people, just their arms/hands.

Comment: So to clarify the context: it's a services company, wanting something that creates a sense of a human connection with their customers, to get across a sense that the customer is dealing with real people not some faceless corporate machine?

Comment: @user568458 No we are not a services company. I find it interesting you even mention that, probably your own preconceived ideas of the type of companies that use the above stock photos. We are a manufacturing company, though really this question should be widely applicable to any company.

Comment: Personally, I've trawled through thousands of photos to find something non-generic, before concluding that the only good option is to take your own picture or illustrate a clever metaphor instead. Looking forward to answers!

Comment: Those generic pictures sell because fairly many want to emulate their peers. So from stock photogrphers point of view its the sort of stuff that you want to make.

Comment: Hire an illustrator. It's hard to fully answer this question without a lot more context. (Also curios as to why your company bans photos...that is just odd)

Comment: @DA01 What type of context do you think is relevant? I can edit. Was trying to keep it somewhat generic so others searching for "alternatives to generic stock girl" could find the question useful as well

Comment: I kind of agree with DA01. Context matters. What *kind* of human interaction? Phone support? Customer service? Technician repairs? Installations? All of the above?

Comment: All of the above really. Something that says we're real people here to support you and provide great customer service. @scott

Comment: @ryan Make a image if a robot that's really stiff, like reverse psychology. Its kind of given you are humans and give great service. Who in their right mind would say anything opposite? In fact even those places that are intentionally crappy say that they give good service and are humans.

Comment: @Ryan, well, if the question is 'alternatives to stock photos' I think that's fine. But the answers will be quite generic too. The common alternatives are: custom photography, illustration, and...well, that's typically the gamut of options right there. :) On the other hand, if you're looking for help with a specific project, that's the context we need. Is this a web site? Brochure? Billboard? Consumer facing? Vendor facing? B2B? That kind of stuff.

Comment: I do have to ask (even though you may not know the answer): Why does the company want to emphasize that they are real humans, but at the same time forbid photographs of said humans? There's a contradiction there at the business level that isn't necessarily resolvable via graphic design.